# Transparent text: what alternatives to the transparent package?

Tags: incompatibility, transparency, transparent

I want to write some text with a semi-transparent color.

I have tried the `transparent` package but it seems to be in conflict with some other package. In a MWE, it works BUT in my real case, it does not work (I load a lot of packages)

So, my question is: **How to make a text semi-transparent, without the `transparent` package?**

---

#### Remark

`\tikz\node[opacity=0.5]{Hello};` does the work but it adds some space after `Hello`.

If you think of another possible solution, I would be interested.

---

PS:
Here is image of what I want to achieve.

[image]

PPS: I need a transparent color and not a plain gray.

Comment: Maybe building a Minimal *Not-Working* Example would help to define which package is clashing with `transparent` and maybe lead to a solution (order of loading? option to activate while loading package? etc.)...

Comment: Yep but I am sure they are easy workarounds!

Comment: `\tikz\node[opacity=0.5]{Hello};` might work. But to really know, we need your MWE, as already mentioned by @ebo.

Comment: Yep but I load approximately 40 packages... `\tikz\node[opacity=0.5]{Hello};` does the work but it adds some space after `Hello`.

Comment: @Colas Try `\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,opacity=0.5]{Hello};`...

Comment: YEP!! Much better!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

EDITED to use Daniel's comment to make the undertext transparent, using a `tikz` node.  The OP mentions in his/her comment to Daniel the presence of "some space after `Hello`", but I'm not sure how that applies to this solution (since the `\stackunder` is centered).

EDITED to take OP's suggestions.  However, I would note that the horizontal alignment of this solution is impervious to `inner sep`, since the underset is automatically centered.  However, the `inner sep` will slightly alter the vertical position of the underset.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,tikz}
\begin{document}
\[
\pagecolor{blue!10}
\stackunder[8pt]{$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t)dt$}{%
  \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.5]{Hello};}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nope, I need transparent.

Comment: @Colas So I edited to use Daniel's suggestion.  Does that suffice?

Comment: I don't have `stackengine` in my distribution it seems.

Comment: @Colas You can go to `https://www.ctan.org/pkg/stackengine` and download the `.sty` file to your working directory to test.  Later, you can figure out how to add it to your installation.

Comment: It works well. I suggest you remove the `black!30` and add `\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.5]`

Comment: And, your package seems to be great ;-)

Comment: @Colas Thanks for the interest in `stackengine`.

Answer (score 6):

A solution with a `tcbox` from `tcolorbox`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\newtcbox{\mybox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.5}

\begin{document}
\pagecolor{blue!10}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
$\displaystyle \int_0^1 f(t) dt$\\
\mybox{Hello} Hello \\
Hello Hello \\
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: ![enter image description here]