# Working with geometry and fontspec packages under the bookcover package

Tags: xetex, geometry, bookcover

## **Problem Description**

The following code from page 30-31 of the `bookcover` package documentation can run only under `pdflatex` as suggested by one of the comments in it:

```
\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
\vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
\resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
\bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
\resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

However, I need assistance on how to make the code executable when I load the `geometry` and `fontspec` packages as provided in the following MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
\usepackage[
a4paper,
left=1in,
right=1in, 
top=1in, 
bottom=1in
]{geometry}
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
\vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}

\begin{bookcover}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
\bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
\draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
\bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
\resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
\color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
\resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
\bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
\resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
\end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

## **Supplementary Information**

Following @S. Venkataraman's comment, I got directed to [Transparent text: what alternatives to the transparent package?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309435/transparent-text-what-alternatives-to-the-transparent-package). I tried both the solutions provided with the intention of looking for `transparent` package substitute under `xelatex`. However, I could get this error: `File ended while scanning use of \bookcovercomponent` on both trials. The MWE of my 2 trials is shown below:

## **1. Trial using `\tikz\node[]{}` command**

Below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
%\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
%\usepackage[
%a4paper,
%left=1in,
%right=1in, 
%top1in, 
%bottom=1in
%]{geometry}
\bookcoverdescgeometry{a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in, 
    top=1in, 
    bottom=1in}%<- Use this instead of using the geometry package.
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
    \vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{bookcover}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
            \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
            \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.1]{\bfseries\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
            \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
                \tikz\node[inner sep=0pt, opacity=0.1]{\bfseries\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
            \resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
        \bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
            \resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
    \end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

## **2. Trial using `tcolorbox` package**

Below is my MWE:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
%\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
%\usepackage[
%a4paper,
%left=1in,
%right=1in, 
%top1in, 
%bottom=1in
%]{geometry}
\bookcoverdescgeometry{a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in, 
    top1in, 
    bottom=1in}%<- Use this instead of using the geometry package.
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
    \vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\newtcbox{\mybox}{blank, on line, opacitytext=0.1}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{bookcover}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
            \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
            \begin{tabular}{c}                   
            \mybox\bfseries\LaTeX
            \end{tabular}}
            \bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
                \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
                \begin{tabular}{c}                   
                \mybox\bfseries\LaTeX
                \end{tabular}}
                \bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
                    \resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
                \bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
                \bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
                    \resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
            \end{bookcover}
        \end{document}
```

### **If possible, I need assistance to make both trials work.**

Comment: you are getting errors because there are missing closing braces.

Comment: Can you please assist with the location that is missing the closing braces, i can't seem to locate it. Thank you.

Comment: Comment parts of you code until the error disappear and then reenable then.

Comment: I did add the closing braces to the rightful locations of the code in trial 1 and 2 respectively and here are the results: 1. Trial 1 code couldn't compile and run, and 2. Trial 2 compiled and run successful though with an undesired opacity, the opacity is not matching with the one in the original code. **However, given that the command `\DocumentMetadata{}` doesn't cause some clash with some other packages or commands, I am willing to add it to my preamble right away since it is the most simple one. @UlrikeFischer. I appreciate tour help.

Answer (score 1):

The following modified version of your code compiles fine in lualatex.  To avoid the option clash with geometry, use the interface given in bookcover package.
Use the command `\bookcoverdescgeometry{⟨geometry parameteres⟩}` given in the bookcover package in page 4.  The transparency package still gives problems in xelatex.  Unless you are using Indic or some other exotic font, Lualatex is all you need.

```
\documentclass[
coverwidth=150mm,
coverheight=220mm,
spinewidth=25mm,
bleedwidth=20mm,
markcolor=black,
foldingmargin,
12pt,
% trimmed % Show only trimmed part!
]{bookcover}
\usepackage{transparent} % It works only with pdflatex
%\usepackage[
%a4paper,
%left=1in,
%right=1in, 
%top1in, 
%bottom=1in
%]{geometry}
\bookcoverdescgeometry{a4paper,
    left=1in,
    right=1in, 
    top1in, 
    bottom=1in}%<- Use this instead of using the geometry package.
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{front} % Trimmed part is the front cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{back} % Trimmed part is the back cover
%\bookcovertrimmedpart{spine} % Trimmed part is the spine
\letnamebookcoverpart{front with margin}{front}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front upper third}{front with margin}[,2\partheight/3,,]
\letnamebookcoverpart{front lower third}{front with margin}[,,,2\partheight/3]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back with margin}{back}[5mm,5mm,5mm,5mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{back text area}{back}[27mm,,22mm,27mm]
\letnamebookcoverpart{bg spine bottom}{bg spine}[,,,\partheight-\bleedwidth-\spinewidth]
\newbookcovercomponenttype{center rotate}{
    \vfill\centering\rotatebox[origin=c]{-90}{#1}\vfill}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{kantlipsum,microtype}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
    
    \begin{bookcover}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg whole}{orange}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front upper third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{front lower third}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{back with margin}{red!60!black}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{front with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (\partwidth-15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{back with margin}{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (15mm,0) -- +(0,\partheight);}
        \bookcovercomponent{tikz}{whole}[5mm,,5mm,]{
            \draw[opacity=0.4,red,line width=10mm] (0,\partheight-20mm) -- +(\partwidth,0);}
        \bookcovercomponent{color}{bg spine bottom}{black}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front upper third}{
            \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
                \color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front lower third}{
            \resizebox*{\partwidth-5mm}{\partheight-5mm}{%
                \color{white}\transparent{0.1}\bfseries\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{center}{front}{
            \resizebox{90mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
        \bookcovercomponent{normal}{back text area}{\color{white}\kant[1-2]}
        \bookcovercomponent{center rotate}{spine}{
            \resizebox{50mm}{!}{\bfseries\color{white}\LaTeX}}
    \end{bookcover}
\end{document}
```

*EDIT* I checked the package documentation. The package author doesn't load `geometry` package explicitly. He does mention that `geometry` package is required. So, the `bookcover` package is probably loading geometry with different options and this is clashing with the options you have used.  So, it is better to use the interface provided by the package author.

Comment: See if this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309435/transparent-text-what-alternatives-to-the-transparent-package is of any help. You may try tcolorbox package instead of transparent.

Comment: Thank you @S. Venkataraman. However, I was not successful in making a substitute for the `transparent` package. Kindly check the modified question.

Comment: the transparent package will work with xelatex (with a current latex) if you load the pdfmanagement by using `\DocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass`.

Comment: How do I load the pdfmanagement @Ulrike Fischer? I haven't done this before. Can you please assist?

Comment: @itc simply add `\DocumentMetadata{}` before `\documentclass`. If you have a current LaTeX this will load the pdfmanagement code from the pdfmanagement-testphase bundle.

Comment: Adding the command `\DocumentMetadata{}` worked perfectly and I am no longer having issues with the `transparent` package under `xelatex`. Out of curiosity, can you please explain the side effects or clashes with other packages or commands, that may happen as a result of adding `\DocumentMetadata{}` in my preamble?